# How to pass text value to action parameter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

i need to pass input value to action method in controller

i have text and button , so I need to click on the button and take the value of input to parameter and re back to the same view but in post status

i tried many things but not works

i tried to create post form and the type of button is submit but does not work

> this is my view code

```
<form method="post">
    <input  type="text" id="Comments" , name="ID" value="" />
    <button type="submit">Go</button>

</form>
```

> this is my controller code

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Entities db = new Entities();
            var Query = from acc in db.tbl_Accounts
                        select acc ;

            var accList= Query.ToList<tbl_Accounts>();
            return View(accList);

        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(int ID)
        {
            Entities db = new Entities();
            var Query = from Acc in db.tbl_Accounts
                        where Acc.id== ID
                        select Acc ;

            var accList= Query.ToList<tbl_Accounts>();
            return View(accList);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view model use `@Html.BeginForm` redirect to action method in controller.

**In View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("youractionname", "yourcontrollername",FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal"}))
{
<input type="text" id="Comments" name="ID" />
    <button type="submit">Go</button>
}
```

**In Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Entities db = new Entities();
            var Query = from acc in db.tbl_Accounts
                        select acc ;

            var accList= Query.ToList<tbl_Accounts>();
            return View(accList);

        }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(int ID)
    {
        Entities db = new Entities();
        var Query = from Acc in db.tbl_Accounts
                    where Acc.id== ID
                    select Acc ;

        var accList= Query.ToList<tbl_Accounts>();
        return View(accList);

    }
```

You have taken an integer datatype in the action method so that you enter the digit value in the textbox

Note: **Please verify your action and controller name In view Model**

Answer (score 0):

There is a few typo mistakes in your code, if you correct it as following then it will work as expected:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" id="Comments" name="ID" />
    <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

So now check only the parameter value, if it is there:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int ID)
{//Put a breakpoint here and check if ID has value

   return View();
}
```

If the value exists there, than assume that it is okay.

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Em9wr.png) that I have tested this answer.